# Rails: How to extract values from JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Very simple question (I am beginner). I have a JSON response from fb containing names and ids:

```
[{"name"=>"John Kline", "id"=>"10276192"}, {"name"=>"Quinn Kumbers",   
 "id"=>"18093781"}, {"name"=>"Dan Jacobs", "id"=>"100000918716828"}] ...
```

How do I extract and access this data in my rails app while preserving its structure? I'd like to be able to tell rails - "give me the id of the 2nd entry", or, "give me the 275th entry" - these sorts of things.

Please assume no knowledge when answering. thx!

Answer (score 8):

without any other gems:

`ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(your_json)`

Answer (score 6):

```
# HT Omar Qureshi
data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(your_json)

# with the id of the 2nd entry
do_something_with(data[1]['id'])

# with the 275th entry
do_something_else_with(data[274])

# loop over all the results
data.each do |datum|
  puts "#{datum['id']}: #{datum['name']}"
end
```