# Handling nested JSON in Rails without accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, backbone.js

I am building a Rails application to provide a JSON API to a Backbone.js frontend.

We have a number of cases where we provide data similar to `label: { id: 1, name: "My Label" }`. When this is used in a select box within a form (to specify an association) we currently need to specify `label_id: 1` in posted data. We'd like the API to be more symmetrical and support the nested `label: { id: 1 }` form if possible.

So far, I (not surprisingly) get a `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch` error as Rails is expecting a `Label` object and receives a `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` instead. I understand we can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` if we want to support nested modification of the labels, but in this case I only want to use the nested form to specify the correct label for the association.

Is there a good way to do this in Rails (3.2.8) that doesn't involve modifying the params hash before passing it off to the model? If not, any recommendations for the best way to robustly transform the params as they come in?

Here's the current code I use to flatten out the params in case it is of help:

```
def flatten_params(hash)
  hash.reduce({}) do |memo, (key, value)|
    if value.class == ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
      memo[(key.to_s + '_id').to_sym] = value['id']
    else
      memo[key] = value
    end
    memo
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

with this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609269/rails-how-to-extract-values-from-json) my buddy Omar says to use `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(your_json)` and the second answer would work, to get at what you need.